# Read text file from 7zip stream by lines

Tags: c#, streaming, 7zip, extract

I have 7z file, which contains one text file, but the text file is very big. I don't want to extract it to folder. I want to open stream and read the file line by line from 7z on-the-fly without any files creation.

I've found SevenZipSharp library. It has SevenZipExtractor class. But I can't see any possibility to get extracted data (and somehow process) without writing to a file:

```
            SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath("c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.dll");
            using (var tmp = new SevenZipExtractor(File.OpenRead(path)))
            {
                tmp.FileExtractionStarted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}%] {1}",
                        e.PercentDone, e.FileInfo.FileName));
                };
                tmp.ExtractionFinished += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Finished!"); };
                tmp.ExtractArchive("E:\\extractFolder");
            }
```

Do you know a way to do what I want?

Comment: I would suggest to consider [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress). Unlike SevenZipSharp it is fully managed (written completely in C#) and has a fairly straightforward interface for obtaining a stream for a specific file in the archive without unpacking it first.

Comment: @AlexeyMitev I tried SharpCompress but didn't find example how to get stream for my purposes. I looked at their test classes on github, but I see only saving to file there. And the author says that 7Zip is not streamable, If I understand correctly.

Comment: I think by "streamable" the author meant that you don't have to have the full ZIP file in order to start unpacking it (i.e. you can download ZIP file from the internet and unpack it at the same time) while 7Zip format doesn't support such thing because it needs to do seeking operations within the .7z file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it with [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress):

```
var archive = SevenZipArchive.Open("test.7z");
var firstFile = archive.Entries.First();
var size = firstFile.Size;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(firstFile.OpenEntryStream()))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```